# how to place an image instaed of a button in zendframework project

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I have a send framework project. Here I have form which contain a code for button see

```
'signup' => array('submit', array(
            'decorators' => $buttonDecorators,
            'label' => 'Next',
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
        ))
    )
```

I need to place an image instead of the submit button. But I don't know how?

Does anyone know this?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: do you mean `Zend` framework?

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to write 'image' instead 'submit';

```
'signup' => array('image', array(
            'decorators' => $buttonDecorators,
            'label' => 'Next',
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
        ))
    )
```

try this.i have not used ZEND framwork yet. but it may helpful to you...

Thanks.

Comment: You can use "src" attribute to set path to your image.